# React components hiding/showing without re-renders

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React app where two tabs.
I want to switch tabs without re-render.
For example code below like my. In this code when `tabValue` changes a new component re-renders.

How I can hide unselected component, but when I will make it visible it won't re-render?

```
<>
  {tabValue === 1 && <SomeComponentTab />}
  {tabValue === 2 && <SomeListTab />}
</>
```

Comment: Like so? `<SomeComponentTab style={{display: tabValue !==1? 'block' : 'none'}} /> <SomeListTab style={{display: tabValue !== 2 ? 'block': 'none'}} />`

Comment: @AdityaParab, Yes, I thought about it. Do you know is it will be good for perfromance?

Comment: Hard to predict whether it would be a performance bottleneck from information in hand.. Also, it's too early to worry about perf.. If it works, it works.. In case of performance impact, that could be handled later on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, a "re-render" occurs whenever any state changes, regardless of if you render a whole new component or you just change some style attributes. However, what it sounds like you're asking about is how to switch between which component is displayed without actually removing either from the DOM or the VDOM.

The best way to do that is to hide the components with CSS. However, rather than modifying the `display` style property of the component directly, it's better to wrap your components in a `div` as in the following code:

```
<>
  <div style={{display: tabValue === 1 ? 'contents' : 'none'}}>
    <SomeComponentTab /> 
  </div>
  <div style={{display: tabValue === 2 ? 'contents' : 'none'}}>
    <SomeListTab />
  </div>
</>
```

And as shown, you should use [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#:%7E:text=boxes%20at%20all.-,contents,-These%20elements%20don%27t) on those `div`'s because it avoids making any assumption about whether the inner components should be displayed as block or inline elements.

This technique is typically used in order to preserve the state of each component between switches, and sometimes it's combined with `React.memo()` to prevent expensive rerenders in situations where users might switch between large components often. The latter use case is due to that React doesn't have to create new DOM elements and reattach event handlers every time the user switches tabs. However, this also creates unnecessary memory pressure on a user's device, which in very extreme cases can actually reverse performance improvements.